# T SQL number groups of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to insert a sequence number in a field, for matching groups, from 3 other fields.

I guess I didn't explain this good enough. Unaware of the RowNumber function I was trying to do a cursor to go through the Records one at a time, but it was NOT really working for me, so I thought I would ask if anyone knew an easier way. I wasn't sure how to incriment through this correctly with the 3 fields, po p0line, and item. Then I also searched StackOverflow for about 3 hours, and I didn't find anything similar to my need. so I posted the question. I have a current condition and target condition example of what I am wanting to do, so I'm not sure how else to word this for some of you who think this is not descriptive enough.

```
    Declare @po_num nvarchar(10)
Declare @po_line int
Declare @po_release int
Declare @item nvarchar(30)
Declare @description nvarchar(40)
declare @due_date datetime
declare @CUR CURSOR 
SET @CUR = CURSOR LOCAL SCROLL STATIC
FOR
SELECT [po_num]
      ,[po_line]
      ,[po_release]
      ,[item]

  FROM [common].[dbo].[PO_ReleaseNumber] p

order by po_num, po_line
open @CUR
fetch NEXT from @CUR

into @po_num,@po_line,@po_release,@item

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 

    update [common].[dbo].[PO_ReleaseNumber] set po_release = 1
where po_num = @po_num and po_line = @po_line and item = @item
    fetch NEXT from @CUR
    into @po_num,@po_line,@po_release,@item
    END


CLOSE @CUR
DEALLOCATE @CUR
GO
```

Example :This is what I have now.

```
po_num  | po_line | Item   | due_date    | Sequence Num
-----------------------------------------------------------
999     | 1       | thing1 | 01/01/2014  |         
999     | 1       | thing1 | 01/15/2014  |     
999     | 1       | thing1 | 01/30/2014  |      
999     | 2       | thing2 | 01/01/2014  |        
999     | 3       | thing2 | 02/13/2014  |         
999     | 3       | thing2 | 03/13/2014  |        
999     | 3       | thing2 | 04/13/2014  |         
999     | 3       | thing2 | 04/15/2015  |
```

This is how I would like to number (sequenceNumber) or po_release number actually.

```
po_num |  po_line| Item    | due_date    | Sequence Num
---------------------------------------------------------
999    |  1      | thing1  | 01/01/2014  | 1 
999    |  1      | thing1  | 01/15/2014  | 2
999    |  1      | thing1  | 01/30/2014  | 3
999    |  2      | thing2  | 01/01/2014  | 1
999    |  3      | thing2  | 02/13/2014  | 1
999    |  3      | thing2  | 03/13/2014  | 2
999    |  3      | thing2  | 04/13/2014  | 3
999    |  3      | thing2  | 04/15/2015  | 4
```

So the table should have actually had a release number for each release of the same PO_num, PO_Line, Item with different release dates and the release number is missing. So I now have to number all of them. There are about 75,000 records all together to go through.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because No Attempt Shown

Comment: Sorry I thought I was being descriptive. But I see Eat a Peach hooked me up and made it look better. I need to get use to how to format posts here I see. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`row_number()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
update [table]
set sequenceNumber = 
    row_number() over (partition by po_num, po_line, item order by due_date)
```

Edit: the above doesn't work because "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses".

To work around that, you could join to a subquery with the windowed function (row_number) in the `select` instead of in the `set` of the outer statement.

Something like this (again, untested):

```
update t
set sequenceNumber = s.rownum
from [table] t
join (
    select po_num, po_line, item, due_date, 
    row_number() over 
        (partition by s.po_num, s.po_line, s.item 
         order by s.due_date) as rownum
) s on t.po_num=s.po_num and t.po_line=s.po_line and 
       t.item=s.item and t.due_date=s.due_date
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me an error. "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses." thanks

Comment: I got it using this.Select
po_num,
po_line, 
row_number() over (partition by po_num, po_line order by due_date) as PO_release,
item,
description,
due_date
into common.dbo.PO_RELEASE
from common.dbo.PO_releaseNumber